# Run image of local dockerfile with a name on a docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a beginner in docker / docker-compose and i'm trying to run a container from a local docker file

my dockerFolder look like this

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── dockerfiles
    ├── dockerfile.test1
    └── dockerfile.test2
```

What did i should put on the docker-compose file ?

I try it but it doesn't work

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  test1:
    build: dockerfiles/dockerfile.test1
  test2:
    build: dockerfiles/dockerfile.test2
```

(I had warned that I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose does not recognize your context, the build argument requires the context (the folder where your Dockerfile is located).
to build from dockerfiles named differently, you must first specify the context and then the name of your dockerfile
as in the following example

```
    version: "3.9"
    services:
      test1:
        build:
          context: ./dockerfiles
          dockerfile: dockerfile.test1
    
      test2:
        build: 
          context: ./dockerfiles
          dockerfile: dockerfile.test1
```

where dockerfile is a subdirectory of parent directory wich contain the docker-compose file

check the docker-compose file reference for more details https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#illustrative-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context` and `dockerfile` to specify a custom `Dockerfile` name like you are doing:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  test1:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
      dockerfile: dockerfile.test1
  test2:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
      dockerfile: dockerfile.test2
```

You can also keep the `build` but naming your files `Dockerfile` and put them of two distinct directories.